# disable sorting on specific columns in ag-grid-react

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid-react and would like to sortable columns in it.

When I put enableSorting=true on , it enables sorting on all the columns. I don't want all columns to be sortable and instead would like sorting to be driven from the columnDef.(E.g sort the column only if its respective columnDef contain sortable=true.

Attaching the sample  and columnDef with codesandbox link

```
<AgGridReact
columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
enableColResize={true}
onGridReady={this.onGridReady.bind(this)}
rowData={this.state.rowData}
enableSorting={true}
/>

columnDefs: [
        {
          headerName: "Athlete",
          field: "athlete",
          width: 150,
          suppressSizeToFit: true
        },
        {
          headerName: "Age",
          field: "age",
          width: 90,
          minWidth: 50,
          maxWidth: 100
        },
        {
          headerName: "Country",
          field: "country",
          width: 120
        },
        {
          headerName: "Year",
          field: "year",
          width: 90
        },
        {
          headerName: "Date",
          field: "date",
          width: 110
        },
        {
          headerName: "Sport",
          field: "sport",
          width: 110
        },
        {
          headerName: "Gold",
          field: "gold",
          width: 100
        },
        {
          headerName: "Silver",
          field: "silver",
          width: 100
        },
        {
          headerName: "Bronze",
          field: "bronze",
          width: 100
        },
        {
          headerName: "Total",
          field: "total",
          width: 100
        }
      ],
```

Please refer : https://codesandbox.io/s/jz317zpo43

Please suggest what needs to be added.

Answer (score 1):

Please check it here. maybe it will help. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/

only enable sorting for a particular column

```
gridOptions: {
    // enable sorting on name and age columns only
    columnDefs: [
        {field: 'name', sortable: true},
        {field: 'age', sortable: true},
        {field: 'address'},
    ]
}
```

Comment: I had seen this and tried. What I don't get is why all columns are sorted by default when enableSorting={true} even if I place sortable:false in column def for few of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve it by upgrading the ag-grid-react and ag-grid-community versions to 20.0.0. Refer AG-644 in https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/